# how to load image before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I have a form which inside it I have an image box with a file input, now i need to show the the picture choosen from file input and show it in my image box without the form to submit.

i found a tutorial which says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

       function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#imgInp").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
                alert(input.val());
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

but this don't show the select image in my image box.

Answer (score 3):

**try this sample js**

```js
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`javascript` at Question appears to return expected result. The issue is placement of `<script>` element or not utilizing `.ready()`. Also, `input` is not defined within `change` event. You can substitute `this.value` for `input.val()` within `change` event handler as parameter to `alert()` call.

Placing `<script>` element beneath `<form>` element at html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  </form>
  <script>
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function() {
      readURL(this);
      alert(this.value);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

using `.ready()` with `<script>` element remaining as child of `<head>` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $().ready(function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }

      $("#imgInp").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
        alert(this.value);
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```